# Magento duplicating the site again asks for write permissions to etc,media, var folders

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I have duplicated my site to another instance. but it is redirecting to old url. As you posted in magento ecommerece, I have deleted local.xml , local.xml.additional. local.xml.template all these files..Then when I try to open my site, it gave me the installation page. Then it is asking for the permissions of var, media, app/etc folders. As I am duplicating the magento folder, it already contains the 777 permissions. SO how can I clear this issue??

Comment: If its asking you for permissions they are definitely incorrect.  How did you copy the files, a lot of methods won't carry permissions.

Comment: after copying to the required instance i am facing this issue. So then I have given 'chmod 777 -R magento'. So it applies 777 permissions to its subfolders also. But then also it is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete your **local.xml** then Magento obviously ask for new installation because it can't locate the **local.xml.**

Restore your **local.xml** and change new credentials in your local.xml.

Comment: after placing the local.xml and its related files, the site is loading, but CSS pages are not loading to it. How can I make it work?

Comment: Thank u for ur answer sir..  It got solved after disabling the selinux.